# MYSQL LIKE with one sign "ó"

Tags: mysql, sign, letter

I have problem with my database query, it work perfectly but when I start search query  and I start "ó" sign, query is ignore about server... Sign "ó" is ignore and "replace" as "o".

Problem is only one letter "ó", with other letter etc. "ąśćźż" is OK.

Database encode and all options encoding is set as UTF-8, in notepad++ is set UTF-8 ( no BOM )

I have tried this query:

```
    $link = $wpdb->esc_like( $link );
    $link = $city.'%'; 
    $sql= "SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CACHE woj FROM city WHERE woj = '$woj'"; 
    $sqlz = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $link, $link ); 
    $query_db = $wpdb->get_results( $sqlz );
```

Comment: post your query also

Comment: $link = $wpdb->esc_like( $link );
$link = $city.'%';
$sql= "SELECT DISTINCT SQL_CACHE woj FROM city WHERE woj = '$woj'"; 
$sqlz = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, $link, $link );
$query_db = $wpdb->get_results( $sqlz );